# ValueError: shapes (5,6) and (5,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: python, backpropagation

I tried to build a model of a neuronal network, which outputs the ValueError between the pretended and actual output. But whenever I tried to run the program following Error is shown on the console:

> ValueError: shapes (5,6) and (5,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

I tried to fix it but unfortunately couldn't solve it. I hope you guys can help me.

Best

So this is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
# X = (Feed rate (fa),Cutting speed (vc),Gangzahl (zo),Heat flux (q),Energy (E)), y = Grinding burn

X = np.array(([0.100,0.300,0.500,0.100,0.500,0.300], [65.000,65.000,65.000,65.000,65.000,35.000], [1.000,1.000,1.000,3.000,3.000,1.000],[1388.830,1279.338,1635.627,1779.128,5905.937,974.872],[10.032,13.176,21.846,4.284,26.295,18.646]),dtype=float)

y = np.array(([1.000], [1.000], [1.000],[1.000],[3.000],[1.000]), dtype=float)



class Training (object):
    def __init__(self):
        #parameters
        self.inputSize = 5
        self.outputSize = 1
        self.hiddenSize = 6
        
        #weights
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize) #  weight matrix from input to hidden layer
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize) #  weight matrix from hidden to output layer
        
    def feedForward(self, X):
        #forward propogation through the network
        self.z = np.dot(X, self.W1) #dot product of X (input) and first set of weights 
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z) #activation function
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2) #dot product of hidden layer (z2) and second set of weights 
        output = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return output
        
    def sigmoid(self, s, deriv=False):
        if (deriv == True):
            return s * (1 - s) #derivitation of sigmoid function
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-s)) #actual sigmoid function
    
    def backward(self, X, y, output):
        #backward propogation through the network
        self.output_error = y - output # error in output
        self.output_delta = self.output_error * self.sigmoid(output, deriv=True)
        
        self.z2_error = self.output_delta.dot(self.W2.T) #z2 error: how much our hidden layer weights contribute to output error
        self.z2_delta = self.z2_error * self.sigmoid(self.z2, deriv=True) #applying derivative of sigmoid to z2 error
        
        self.W1 += X.T.dot(self.z2_delta) # adjusting first set (input -> hidden) weights
        self.W2 += self.z2.T.dot(self.output_delta) # adjusting second set (hidden -> output) weights
        
    def train(self, X, y):
        output = self.feedForward(X)
        self.backward(X, y, output)
        
NN = Training ()

for i in range(1000): #trains the NN 1000 times
    if (i % 100 == 0):
        print("Loss: " + str(np.mean(np.square(y - NN.feedForward(X)))))
    NN.train(X, y)
        
print("Input: " + str(X))
print("Actual Output: " + str(y))
print("Loss: " + str(np.mean(np.square(y - NN.feedForward(X)))))
print("\n")
print("Predicted Output: " + str(NN.feedForward(X)))
```